# Is there any alternative to build a Java editor without Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Some context here first. We currently have a tool that is written in Eclipse, a RCP app, that is basically a Java Editor simplified that also does some other basic stuff (not relevant at the moment)

The problem we're having is that is just too big, whenever we use it we face a lot problems because its a memory hog, and it feels slow. So I'm considering alternatives to using Eclipse. I know I can probably do all the front-end stuff easily with Swing, SwingX or JavaFX (just to name a few) but I'm more worried about the built-in capabilities that Eclipse provides to create a code editor (intellisense-code syntax highlight and checker, etc)...will this be possible to replace out of Eclipse? Are there any projects out there that could be used for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you build an editor with NetBeans? @AdityaSingh never tought we could one could do that

Comment: It is possible to create an editor using just Javafx (as I did), but it will take a lot of time. I've been making mine in Intellij community edition. How much memory does your editor consume?

Comment: This talk comes to mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7AMOmjQDlw

Comment: Given the amount of feature in the regular Eclipse editor and it's relatively good performances, I tend to believe that maybe your specific editor is to blame more than Eclipse itself. Did you try to find memory leaks? Profile your code? Run static analysis to find bad smells...?

Comment: @Mickael not yet, but is not the first time that I've built a somewhat complex RCP and the results are always the same: memory consumption over the top (like having a regular Eclipse), tons of plug-ins included that increse payload size of final product, and performance is "slow"...I guess I'd need to do that, but just wondering if there any real alternatives out there

Comment: @AlejandroVK All that depends on which features you need... If you want an IDE that does everything like JDT's one, you'll have trouble to find something lighter - for example NetBeans and IntelliJ are similar in term of resources & perf.

Comment: @Mickael I understand, I only need the intellisense, syntax-highlight and syntax checker, although some JDT has been modified already to change the way blocks of code are shown...so I guess decoupling from that won't be easy

Comment: There are 2 implementations of a Language Server for Java you can interact with (see https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol/wiki/Protocol-Implementations ). The Language Server Protocol can provide completion, syntax checkers and more... as a "blackbox". They're also consuming resources and can be slow, but it's in a separate process.
Most other editors rely on TextMate grammars for coloration, since this is not part of such protocol at the moment.